# A problem about Sylow Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

I'm learning Sylow Theorem. My textbook uses the following result directly and does not tell me why. I don't know how to prove it.

$C_{p^rn}^{p^r}\equiv n \mod pn$. Here $p$ is a prime number and $r,n$ are positive integers.

Comment: Which textbook are you referring to?

Answer (score 3):

We assume $n$ and $p$ are coprime. Then $\binom{p^rn}{p^r}=n\binom{p^rn-1}{p^r-1}$, so it’s enough to show that $N=\binom{p^rn-1}{p^r-1}$ is congruent to $1$ mod $p$.

Now, in $\mathbb{F}_p$, $N$ is the coefficient of $X^{p^r-1}$ in $(X+1)^{p^rn-1}$. But (mod $p$ by Fermat’s little theorem, $(X+1)^{p^rn-1}=(X+1)^{p^r(n-1)}(X+1)^{p^r-1}=(X^{p^r}+1)^{n-1}(X+1)^{p^r-1}$, and it’s easy to show that the coefficient of $X^{p^r-1}$ in the polynomial in the right hand side is $1$.